# postgres autovacuum retry mechanism

Tags: postgresql

In postgres, when autovacuum runs and for some reason say its able to perform autovacuum - for example when hot_standby_feedback is set and there are long running queries on standby. Say for example tab1 has been updated and it triggers autovacuum, meanwhile a long running query on standby is running and sends this info to primary which will skip the vacuum on tab1.

Since the autovacuum got skipped for tab1, When does autovacuum run vacuum on the table again? Or it will not run autovacuum again on it and we would need to manually run vacuum on that table. Basically does autovacuum retry autovacuum on tables that could not be vacuumed for the first time?

Comment: Read [Autovaccum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autovacuum does not get skipped due to hot_standby_feedback.  It still runs, it just might not accomplish anything if no rows can be removed.  If this is the case, then pg_stat_all_tables.n_dead_tup does not get decremented, which means that the table will probably get autovacuumed again the next time the database is assessed for autovacuuming as the stats that make it eligible have not changed.  On an otherwise idle system, this will happen about once every however long it takes to scan not-all-visible part of the table, rounded up to the next increment of autovacuum_naptime.

It might be a good idea (although the use case is narrow enough that I doubt it) to suppress repeat autovacuuming of a table until the horizon has advanced far enough to make it worthwhile, but currently there is no code to do this.

Note that this differs from INSERT driven autovacuums.  There, n_ins_since_vacuum does get reset, even if none of the tuples were marked all visible.  So that vacuum will not get run again until the table cross some other threshold to make it eligible.